# Assigning Alternate Color to a List Elements

Tags: wpf, linq, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a class as below

```
public class Account
{
    public string TransferFromIndicator { get; set; }
    public string AccNickname { get; set; }
    public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
    public string AccIndex { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush RowColor { get; set; }
}
```

All the data other than RowColor property is being set from backend data. While retriving the data from backend I want to select every alternate color as Black i.e first items color as White next items color is white this goes on. I have been trying to do this with below snippet. Can you please help me how could I set up different rowcolor for alternate elements.

```
  List<Account> newList = from x in AccountList select new Account
  { 
       TransferFromIndicator=TransferFromIndicator 
       AccNickname = AccNickname,
       RowColor = 
  }
```

Comment: How do you assign `AccIndex`? As soon as you've got that, you might set `RowColor = new SolidColorBrush((AccIndex % 2 == 0) ? Colors.Black : Colors.White)`. Of course only if AccIndex is the row index.

Comment: I AccIndex is random. I can set it to Sequential no even. That could solve my problem. Other than using AccIndex is there any way?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/alternate-row-color-in-listbox-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lst">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccNickname}" Foreground="{Binding RowColor}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

CS:

```
    public class Account
    {
        public string TransferFromIndicator { get; set; }
        public string AccNickname { get; set; }
        public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
        public string AccIndex { get; set; }
        public string RowColor { get; set; }

        public Account() { }
        public Account(string TransferFromIndicator,string AccNickname,string AccountStatus,string AccIndex,string RowColor)
        {
            this.TransferFromIndicator = TransferFromIndicator;
            this.AccNickname = AccNickname;
            this.AccountStatus = AccountStatus;
            this.AccIndex = AccIndex;
            this.RowColor = RowColor;
        }
    }

        void loadData()
        {
            List<Account> objAccount = new List<Account>();
            objAccount.Add(new Account("data", "data", "data", "data", "White"));
            objAccount.Add(new Account("data", "data", "data", "data", "Black"));
            objAccount.Add(new Account("data", "data", "data", "data", "White"));
            objAccount.Add(new Account("data", "data", "data", "data", "Black"));
            objAccount.Add(new Account("data", "data", "data", "data", "White"));
            objAccount.Add(new Account("data", "data", "data", "data", "Black"));
            lst.ItemsSource = objAccount;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            loadData();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a converter for this. there is also an alternate row color implementation floating around the internet for a listbox control.

Doing it your way:

```
public class Account
{
    public string TransferFromIndicator { get; set; }
    public string AccNickname { get; set; }
    public string AccountStatus { get; set; }
    public string AccIndex { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush RowColor { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public void BindData()
    {
        var accounts = new List<Account>
        {
            new Account { AccIndex = "One", AccNickname = "First Account", AccountStatus = "Closed", TransferFromIndicator = "xyz" },
            new Account { AccIndex = "Two", AccNickname = "Second Account", AccountStatus = "Open", TransferFromIndicator = "xyz" },
            new Account { AccIndex = "Third", AccNickname = "Third Account", AccountStatus = "Pending", TransferFromIndicator = "xyz" },
            new Account { AccIndex = "Fourth", AccNickname = "Fourth Account", AccountStatus = "Closed", TransferFromIndicator = "xyz" },
            new Account { AccIndex = "Fifth", AccNickname = "Fifth Account", AccountStatus = "Open", TransferFromIndicator = "xyz" },
            new Account { AccIndex = "Sixth", AccNickname = "Sixth Account", AccountStatus = "Pending", TransferFromIndicator = "xyz" }
        };

        var index = 0;
        accounts.ForEach(a => { a.RowColor = ((index % 2 == 0) ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)); index++; });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct you tag. Do you need solution for WPF or Windows Phone ? Try below given code.

XAML

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:AlternateColor x:Name="AlternateColor" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbx">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AlternateColor}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransferFromIndicator}" Foreground="GreenYellow" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccNickname}" Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountStatus}" Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccIndex}" Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

To get data

```csharp
var list = new List<Account>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Account
    {
        AccIndex = Path.GetRandomFileName(),
        AccNickname = Path.GetRandomFileName(),
        AccountStatus = Path.GetRandomFileName(),
        TransferFromIndicator = Path.GetRandomFileName()
    });
}

/*if you don't want to use converter

List<Account> newList = from x in AccountList select s;

bool ThrowBlack = false;
foreach (var item in s)
{
    if (ThrowBlack)
    {
        ThrowBlack = false;
        item.RowColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
    }
    else
    {
        ThrowBlack = true;
        item.RowColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
    }
}

*/

lbx.ItemsSource = list;
```

Converter

```
public class AlternateColor : IValueConverter
{
    bool ThrowBlack = false;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var obj = (Account)value;
        if (ThrowBlack)
        {
            ThrowBlack = false;
            obj.RowColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
            return obj.RowColor;
        }
        else
        {
            ThrowBlack = true;
            obj.RowColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
            return obj.RowColor;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```